# Jagged and ugly Shadows in Eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, shadows

I’ve created a low-poly stylized tree in Blender 2.8 and rendered it with Eevee. Some of the shadows on the leaves are very jagged and quite ugly.

The entire scene is simply a camera, a sun light source and a few meshes with a single material each for the tree.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I’ve played a little with the sun light settings but it only seemed to shift where the jaggedness was occurring. I've taken a look at some similar threads on StackExchange but the suggestions didn't seem to help.

[Here is the .blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BpfqpD7o7n9Pa_Yn8XEt74s4yLmU-2gt/view?usp=sharing)

Ideally, I’m not simply chasing a “how to fix it”. I don’t have much knowledge on 3D modelling and rendering, so any explanations as to *why* this is occurring would be great!

Comment: Please only use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload .blend files. Please read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the inaccurate behavior of **Shadow Mapping** used in real time rendering enginnes like EEVEE and almost all game rendering engines. People call them **Shadow Acne**.

What you see is actually pixelated shadow mapping to some boundary area, causing those *alias* shadow show on the mesh.

There are many solutions to overcome this problem, but since performance is the main issue in real-time rendering, the best solution changes depend on the situation of your application.

You can check out this explanation about shadow mapping: [Shadow Mapping - LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Shadows/Shadow-Mapping)

---

### Blender 2.81 Update Information

According to the [latest Blender](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.81/Eevee),

> Soft shadows were changed and now enabled with the `Use Soft Shadow` option in the render properties Shadow panel. This will progressive smooth shadows, in combination with a more conventional shadow filtering method (PCF). Exponential and Variance Shadow Mapping methods were removed. ([d8aaf25c23fa](http://developer.blender.org/rBd8aaf25c23fa))

The way EEVEE render shadow has been changed to a more common method. And the problem of Shadow Acne should be reduce or even solved. Check for the latest Blender to see whether the shadow has been fixed.

Comment: As a follow up question, lets say I was wanting it to look like these low-poly trees: https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/warehouse/v1.0/publiccontent/74467b6f-3fb5-4bd7-9ef9-872bf9e0752d How would you go about fixing the issue i'm describing?

As an aside, i've been interested in learning OpenGL (and graphics programming in general) for a while. Have you found it helps you in your 3D modelling?

Comment: @daviegravee You could change the light properties under your light sources, which might fix some problem. And under the render properties > Shadows, you might use higher Size depend on your light type, soft shadow might work as well. And for learning computer graphic, **yes it help a lot**, you can get more clear about what can be achieved in general method, making your modeling pipeline more robust.